# how to denote summation in direct sum of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

**Short version**

If $\hat{u}$ is a unit vector in an $n$-dimensional space $U$, and $\hat{w}$ is a unit vector in an $n$-dimensional space $W$, is there an unambiguous notation to express that
$$
  v = \hat{u} + \hat{w}
$$
is a decomposition of a $(2n)$-dimensional vector in $V = U \oplus W$, **yet also** allow the notation $\hat{u} \in S^{n-1}$ and $\hat{w} \in S^{n-1}$ without implying that $\hat{u}$ and $\hat{w}$ lie in the same $n$-dimensional space and that $\hat{u} + \hat{w}$ does as well?

**Details**

If $V$ is an $(2n)$-dimensional vector space with the direct sum decomposition
$$ V = U \oplus W $$
where $U$ and $W$ are $n$-dimensional, then for any $v \in V$ corresponds a unique pair of vectors $u \in U, w \in W$ such that
$$
  v = u + w.
$$
But I recently encountered the **mixed polar-cartesian decomposition**
$$
  v = \Vert v \Vert \sin \theta \hat{u} + \Vert v \Vert \cos \theta \hat{w}
$$
where $\hat{u} = \frac{u}{\Vert u \Vert_U}$ and $\hat{w} = \frac{w}{\Vert w \Vert_W}$ are unit vectors in their respective subspaces.  It is natural to also write $\hat{u} \in S^{n-1}$ and $\hat{w} \in S^{n-1}$, where $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere in $n$-dimensional space.  I have seen this notation used in [polyspherical coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-sphere#Polyspherical_coordinates).  But clearly something is being elided here, because we seem to allow
$$\hat{u} \in S^{n-1} \subset U$$
and
$$\hat{w} \in S^{n-1} \subset W,$$
yet $U \cap W = \{0\}$ for any linear subspaces that we "add" with $\oplus$.

Conceptually I understand that I mean "$\hat{u}$ is a unit vector in the $(n-1)$-sphere embedded in the first $n$ dimensions of $V$ and $\hat{w}$ is a unit vector in the $(n-1)$-sphere embedded in the last $n$ dimensions of $V$" or something to that effect.  I don't really know any more concise way to state this or denote it, however.

Furthermore, I feel like this problem is occurring somehow at the boundary between the direct sum notation
$$
V = U \oplus W
$$
and the cartesian product notation
$$
V = \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n.
$$
It seems that $\mathbb{R}^n \oplus \mathbb{R}^n$ is nonsensical, since *e.g.* in Linear Algebra Done Right (Axler), this direct sum notation is reserved for subspaces which intersect only at $\{0\}$.